# How safe is this Navigation with php

Tags: php, security, navigation

How safe is this, if I **would** want to use it as a "navigation system"?

```
$p="main";              
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $p=$_GET['page'];
    if($p!=basename($p) || !preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+$/",$p) || $p=="index" || !file_exists($p.".php"))
        $p="error";
    }
include($p.".php");
```

*Actually I know, this is not good, one reason is: you can't include subfolders. The main question is, how safe it is.*

Comment: `$p=$_GET['page'];` This should answer your question. This script is inviting me to execute every php script i want on your server. I hope you have no upload function in there.

Comment: Create an array with all valid folders to validate it

Comment: No, a friend of me is using this and he is not believing me, he says, that he is checking with *pregmatch()*, *file_exists()*, so, only some php-files could be included. sigh!

Comment: If i upload a script, it exists. And if i name it properly, it will get through the regex. So whats the problem? This stuff is unsafe as hell. Nothing is more scarier than zombie-includes.

Comment: `switch ($s) {
case 'home':
include('includes/main.php'); 
break;
case 'site1':
include('includes/site1.php'); 
break;
default: 
include('includes/main.php');   
}`
Something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following script gives you a good, secure and manageable navigation.

```
$allowed_pages = array(
    'home' => 'main.php',
    'contacts' => 'contacts.php',
    'foo' => './demo_folder/foo.php',
);

if(isset($_GET['page'])
    && array_key_exists($_GET['page'], $allowed_pages))
{
    $p = $_GET['page'];
    $file_to_include = $allowed_pages[$_GET['page']];

    include $file_to_include;
}
else
{
    //fallback for when redirect does not work properly
    echo 'Page not found. Return to <a href="./">main page</a>';

    //redirect to main page
    header('Location: ./');
    exit();
}
```